# How to make dictionary using two lists which contains multiple values for one key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I want to make a dictionary out of the two lists "a" and "b" in which a contains the keys and b contains values but the problem is that there are multiple values for one key

```
a=['Eng','Eng','Eng','Science', 'Science' ,'Hindi','Maths','Maths']
b=['Noun','Pronoun','Tenses','Light','Sound','Algebra','Probability']
```

expected output should be like

```
{'Eng':['Noun','Pronoun','Tenses'],'Science':['Light','Sound'],'Maths':['Algebra','Probability']}
```

Comment: Why does `Hindi` not appear in the expected output?  Why is your expected output expected?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra entry in `a` in your input. Removing the extra `Hindi` from `a` so that `len(a) = len(b)`. You can use following small snippet -

```
d = {}
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
```

output `d` -

```
{'Eng': ['Noun', 'Pronoun', 'Tenses'], 'Science': ['Light', 'Sound'], 'Maths': ['Algebra', 'Probability']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly because our system doesn't know why Noun belongs to English. To get this output, you must create a relation like.

```
#Your expected relation
Eng = [ 'Noun' , ' Pronoun',  ' Tenses']
Hindi = ['Algebra'] 
Science = [ 'Light', 'Sound']
Maths = [' Probability']

#Your Given Data
a=['Eng','Eng','Eng','Science', 'Science' ,'Hindi','Maths','Maths']
b=['Noun','Pronoun','Tenses','Light','Sound','Algebra','Probability']

Answer={}
#eliminating multiple keys.
new_a=[]
for i in a:
    if i in new_a:
          new_a.append(i)
    else:
          pass

#Assign the values using key value pair.
```